# elasticsearch custom scoring based on date field

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch, scoring

how do I write a custom script in Elasticsearch to check a date field and score by giving more relevance to difference between current date and the date in the field? Basically if the difference is negative value, I would want to show that result first.

Comment: I am able to get the value of the field in script score. But I want to get the difference of the same with the current date.

Answer (score 0):

It would be the best if you can use [function score query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) 
There is a script type function there -

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": { // Your query //},
      "function": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "lang": "groovy",
            "script": "doc['dateA'].value - doc['dateB'].value"
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "replace" // Remove score from query and replace it with the score from script
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not very conversant with Groovy. What I want to do is DateA value difference from current date. How do I go about it?

Comment: Why do you want a minus from the current date ? Instead cant you do a sort based on that date field. Changing the order should work for you.

Comment: It would. But I want to display the score (as number of days overdue or due in) on the frontend.